# MFC project migrated from VC 6.0 to VS2015. Unable to launch the dialogBox, GUI

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, migration

I got a MFC project which is in VC 6.0 and migrated it to VS2015. After resolving the compiler, linker problems when I debug the application I found that `InitInstance` method is not getting called. The main class is derived from `CWinApp` and `Initinstance` method is overridden.

Can anyone suggest on this?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm trying to post the same! but its very huge, so will remove the dependencies and post the sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason, as it is calling a global object which makes a call to initialize a dialog with ActiveX controls. And there controls are not registered, so it is throwing an error which was not captured properly in the code.